# Server side conflict resolving, Azure Mobile Services (.NET backend)

Tags: .net, conflict, azure-mobile-services, azure-android-sdk

I want to know if there is a way to detect and resolve conflicts from .NET backend server project of Azure mobile services. I know how to do it from the client side, but the first approach will solve some of my problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, server side conflict resolution is possible.  This test backend has a very simple client vs server example here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services-test/blob/master/Runtime/DotNetE2EServerApp/Controllers/Table/RoundTripTableController.cs#L44

I'd need to look around for a more detailed guide, but hopefully the above is enough to get you started.